# Fishing Lure Physics

Tags: physics

I want to animate a fishing lure using physics but I'm not sure of the best way to set this up. My dilemma is when a lure is cast, the lure becomes the leading object that pulls everything with it ie. the line hook etc. until it hits the water. Then, when you begin to reel the slack in the line tightens and it becomes the leading object pulling the lure and hook

Comment: What have you got so far? Could you post some screenshots of what you have achieved already?

Comment: As far as I know, first part (casting lure) is somewhat possible - using rigid and soft/cloth bodies but the second one (pulling the lure under water) isn't achievable with simulation, as soft bodies and fluid simulations are completely different solvers. Maybe cheating like making lure soft/cloth bodies and trying to apply force field to it can help.